# How to round a whole number in R

Tags: r, rounding

This is a really simple question but how do I round a number in R such that I only show 2 significant figures?

E.g. 326 rounds to 330 and 4999 rounds to 5000

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Use digits to indicate decimal places.

```
round(326, digits=-1)
[1] 330
```

Here is the difference between `signif()` and `round()`. Taken directly from documentation:

```
x2 <- pi * 100^(-1:3)
round(x2, 3)
signif(x2, 3)

[1]       0.031       3.142     314.159   31415.927 3141592.654
[1] 3.14e-02 3.14e+00 3.14e+02 3.14e+04 3.14e+06
```

Use the one that works for you.

Comment: This is pretty nice ! I never knew you could use negative digits to round up above 'unit' level.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this could help:

```
signif(4999,2)
5000

signif(326,2)
330

signif(326232,2)
330000
```

And as Jim O. pointed out, there is a difference between `signif()` and `round()`. Also in performances are different, due as pointed out by Gregor, this could be not too much *useful* to know but maybe *interesting*:

```
library(microbenchmark)
k <- sample(1:100000,1000000,replace=T)  
microbenchmark(
    round_ ={round(k, digits=-1)},
    signif_ ={signif(k,2)} 
)

Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
  round_  68.56366  70.22595  74.02643  71.99918  75.32761 109.5727   100
 signif_ 109.57957 111.86501 121.17458 114.13232 118.88837 495.0321   100
```

Comment: Pretty pointless to post performance benchmarks in nanoseconds on rounding a single number. If you're going to go to the bother to benchmark something, at least do it at a scale where it *might* make a difference. (Though it's unlikely that rounding with either of these functions will ever be a performance bottleneck.)

Comment: @Gregor I did not mean to bother anyone and, if I did it, I'd like to excuse to whom has been bothered (also, I gave +1 to the Jim O. answer, that I liked): I would only add something I generally like to do on my own, hoping it helps. Your point is valid, I added a -probably- more significative benchmarking, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No bother! I upvoted your answer when I commented, it's good! Just wanted to point out that the benchmarks weren't useful as posted, and hopefully to stop other people from seeing them as an example of something worth doing or considering.

Comment: If you look back, you'll see on the 1 number benchmark, the median time for `signif` was 1 ns, vs 428 for `round`, implying signif is ~40000% faster, an absurd result. With this more reasonable example, we get a result in the opposite direction and of a reasonable magnitude, `round` is ~36% faster. However, the point still stands that both of these functions are so quick that it's difficult to imagine either one being a performance bottleneck. Due to both that and the fact the functions do (slightly) different things, the benchmark may be *interesting* but I don't think it's actually *useful*.

Comment: I've seen what you say, I hope that your comments could make the answer more useful and leaving the future readers the chance to get an opinion about: in my mind, I'm with you, it's **not useful** for this case.

Comment: Cool. I liked this answer too. I didn't even think about performance differences.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
round(3333,-1)
round(3333,-2)
```

and see what you get